# Can I consolidate this code? Or is there a better solution?

Tags: ocaml, higher-order-functions

I am creating a function that sums all of the numbers in a list of integer lists. Here is my current solution:

```
let rec super_sum (nlists : int list list) : int =
  let acc = 0 in
  match nlists with
  | [] -> 0
  | head :: tail ->
    match tail with 
    | [] -> List.fold_left (+) acc head
    | list -> List.fold_left (+) acc head + super_sum list ;;
```

I feel like I can consolidate this a bit. I use `List.fold_left (+) acc head` twice and I feel I can create some function that can prevent this.

Comment: There is a one-line implementation, yes. You can use two *nested* folds to calculate the entire result.

Comment: Also note that your value `acc` has no real purpose. It is an immutable 0 value. So you could just use 0 everywhere you have `acc`. It's certainly not an accumulator in any sense.

Answer (score 1):

I won't give you the answer because it's much better if you can find it yourself but I'll give you some hints to find it.

1. The first thing you need to do is sum all the elements of an `int list` and this is what you already do with `List.fold_left (+) acc head`
2. The second thing you need to do now is to iterate on your lists of lists and sum the sums you compute on your first step. The thing is, you already know how to sum a list of integers from this step so instead of summing the elements you just need to sum the sum of elements

I can't even provide a skeleton since it would give you the immediate solution.